# Code with ?, Compile in Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, actionscript-3

So I'm jumping into iPhone development and I've begun looking into Objective-C and have noticed that... it sucks. Ultimately, there's all kinds of odd syntax requirements, ex:

```
NSString *city = @"Victoria";
```

or

```
[MyClass myMethod]
```

This is alien. The language should be smart enough to know what do do with a normal variable and string.

But, this is the language, and I can't do anything about it. So, my main question is: Is there any way to write my code in PHP/AS3/C# or some other normal language and then compile or convert it to legal Objective-C? I was going to use AS3 but necessary functionality like the Camera is not currently supported.

I know it's an odd question, but what about when I need to develop for Android or Windows 7? There are only so many languages one can learn before one loses his/her mind. I'd like to stop at 7.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a limit to the languages one can learn. Ulitimately they're all quite similar anyway, just a bit of different syntax here and there.

Comment: @Vilx, so you know dozens of languages and never forget syntax differences or get confused? Come on. I'm being reasonable and all I ask is that those who participate in this discussion act the same.

Comment: Waaait, wait wait wait... you think Objective-C sucks and you want to write PHP and *convert* it to Objective-C?

Comment: @dreamlax Objective-C is in between 1980's programming and modern OOP. They still hang on to "NS" for God's sake.

Comment: Hang on to NS?  It's to avoid namespace collisions...

Comment: @dcolumbus: No Objective-C doesn't suck.  Lots of people use it to create great applications.  It's far more in the spirit of real OOP than Java or C++ which also have their roots in the 80's, incidentally.

Comment: Nop. Currently at about 8, not counting HTML/CSS, though 2 of them I haven't used in a while (qbasic and vb.net). I know the basics of a few more (I can read and reason out most code written in them). And I feel like I could learn several more without breaking sweat. :) Of course, you rarely need to use more than a few at a time (currently I'm actively using only C#, Javascript and PHP, with a smidgeon of Pascal now and then). So when you're switching over to a lesser used language, sure, there is a little time of confusion. But that doesn't last long.

Comment: @Jeremy, yes, they all have ancient roots... but the real issue I have is that the language isn't "smart" enough to deal with standard variable declarations. I mean, calling a Class and method with multiple arguments in Obj-C looks like a horrible mess.

Comment: @jn_pdx: To be fair, Objective-C would be improved with real support for namespaces. In most other respects, it is a great language and I really don't understand whty people whine about a slightly different syntax.  Not everything has to look exactly like Java.

Comment: However I'm willing to admit that all people aren't equal, and others might not have it as easy as me. I'm sorry. Though I still think that you should take the time and learn the language, as it will open you a lot of doors in the Mac world. Trust me, your brain won't explode. And you don't need to start with 3 heavy bibles either. Just get some tutorials, get the basics down, and start playing around. Soon enough you'll know all you need to build good apps.

Comment: @dcolumbus: Of course Objective-C can deal with standard variable declarations.  It's exactly like C but with some OO additions.  You have to do some things slightly differently for the OO stuff, but you soon get used to it.

Comment: @dreamlax, yeah, a php developer complaining about $odd -> syntax :: requirements ;)) @dcolumbus: have a look at http://www.appcelerator.com/

Comment: @Jeremy, I'm seriously not arguing against the ability to "get used to it" ... as I said above, this is the language and I can't do anything to change it. It's just a very left field approach compared to 90% of the languages out there. I mean, Obj-C needs to compile anyway, so why not just go the extra step and clean up this need to treat `int` and `NSString` differently? Just allow me to say `int` or `string` ... and don't even get me started on the use of `*`

Comment: @dreamlax, I never said I was a PHP developer. The `$odd->syntax` is ridiculous. I'm a ActionScripter first.

Comment: @JeremyP agreed.
@dcolumbus -- there are actually some really nice things about the syntax (which doesn't take too long to get used to), such as the myMethod: withVar: andOtherVar: named argument style.  Takes a lot of the guessing (or at least memory games) out of dealing with frameworks

Comment: I think any syntax will look odd if you haven't used it before. Have you but any idea [how many programming languages there are](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/abc.html)? Do you really expect them all to use the same syntax?

Comment: @jn_pdx, yeah... I do appreciate that much of it. Look, how about I ask you fine gentlemen a more pointed question: beyond these initial road blocks that I don't care for, how much more of the language will I be fighting with? Does it stop at these initial ones?

Comment: Anyways... I think we digress here. The qualities of the syntax of the language aren't up for discussion.

Comment: @dcolumbus - in short, yes, that's the biggest hump to get over.  Dealing with the frameworks, however definitely has a learning curve, but you'll have to deal with them no matter what language you choose (eg, the APIs for the camera have to be accessed at some point using the CocoaTouch framework)

Comment: @dcolumbus - if you start using it actively (as in, 8 hours a day), I predict about two weeks of serious fighting; then about 2 months of using google more often that usually; and then you'll think it as natural as any other language.

Comment: @Vilx -- I think that's a pretty high estimate for amount of time fighting.  I may have spent two weeks struggling at the beginning, but that was only spending an hour or so a day on it.

Comment: @Vilx: @jn_pdx: I agree with jn_pdx, I got the basics down in a few hours (it will obviously take longer if you are not already a competent C programmer) and I was confident with the language in less than a month programming a couple of hours a day.

Comment: @jn_pdx - probably, but better overestimate. And, as I said, different people have different talents. His might lay elsewhere than learning programming languages. So I gave a cautios estimate. If the real time is less then that - all the better. :)

Comment: Any question claiming that a language, or OS, or some other such thing "sucks" in the first sentence is going to be closed as "subjective and argumentative".  If you would replace your opinions on Objective-C with something like "I really don't get Objective-C, and don't want to program in it.", that would help greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd better write a real answer instead of expressing my thoughts piecemeal in comments.

I think you should stick with it because for somebody coming from the world of Java or .Net or C++ things do look a bit strange at first.  However, once you understand the paradigm, you realise that, in  OO terms, Java, C++ and .Net are only half way there.  The Objective-C model turns out to be extraordinarily powerful for such a small language.

In real OO as per the Smalltalk model, you do not call methods on objects,you send messages to them and they decide what to do.  C++ style language only provide a limited form of this through inheritance.  Objective-C goes the whole way.  This is why, incidentally, the syntax for "calling" methods on Objective-C objects is different to normal function calls, it's because it is not a function call.

As for the syntax, well the example you gave is the way it is because a C style string is a completely different thing to a NSString.  The first is just a pointer and a sequence of bytes terminated with a null byte, the second is a proper string object.  The compiler has to have a way of differentiating the two without breaking C compatibility.

As for the message passing syntax, well it seems strange at first, but once you get used to the interleaved parameters, the advantages become plain.  Objective-C methods are much more self documenting than those of traditional C like languages.

There are only two major areas in which Objective-C falls short (in my opinion) and they are the lack of namespace support and (on iOS) the lack of proper garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy. I was hoping you'd write out a real answer. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Question: what should one focus on when there is a strong need to develop Apps for multiple platforms? I spend all this time focusing on Obj-C, but that get's me no where with Android, Windows 7 or Blackbery. Recommendations? Perhaps I'll ask this question separately.

Comment: Well, Adobe AIR covers Android, iOS, Win 7, and Playbook. No support on Blackberry currently, and if you meant Win *phone* 7 then AIR doesn't cover that yet either... Another option would be an HTML-based interface with some amount of native app underneath. At least Android and iOS should support that; I don't know about the others. Edit: and MONO, per moon's answer too!

Comment: The problem with the AIR option is that it doesn't support necessary functionality like the Camera and Microphone.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at MonoTouch: [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)
I can feel with you, I was coming from C# to Objective C about a year ago and it ws very painful to learn the syntax

Oh, and of course the Adobe Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: Yeah, Flash is a nice option, except for the fact that there are too many functions that are not available, i.e. the Camera.

Comment: Check out AIR 2.6. Adds support for camera, mic, and a lot else. As of 2.6, iOS AIR is basically at feature parity with Android.  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios_features_in_air26.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write code natively for iOS, Android, and Windows 7 using C++.  The libraries you'll have available on the different platforms will vary of course, but it'll be a common syntax across the board.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot convert the code into objective C but the mono project enables you to develop iPhone apps in c# look at [this](http://cplus.about.com/b/2009/01/11/the-biggest-iphone-development-surprise-yet-c.htm)

- [MONO TOUCH](http://monotouch.net/)
- [MONO TOUCH for iphone 4](http://www.mono-project.com/newstouch/archive/2010/Apr-09.html)
- [SOME OTHER INFO](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2011/01/31/c-for-the-iphone-monotouch-is-here-to-stay/)

[get it from here](http://monotouch.net/DownloadTrial)

Comment: and ADOBE also looking forward that the flash player and adobe air will come to iOS this year

Comment: AIR is on iOS already! No flash in the browser though, until iOS allows third-party plugins.